# Content of grid item is overflowing its box

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple grid and the content of the two of the grid items overflow and get out of the their grid item.

Here's my code which is partly copied from [this post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#aa-grid-template-areas):

```css
body{ 
    background-color: #E3E3E3;

}
#six.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
    [row1-start] "header header header" 40px [row1-end]
    [row2-start] "footer footer footer" 25px [row2-end]
    / auto 50px auto;
    background-color: #FFF3E8;

}

#six .item{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #F78100;
    background-color: #F89426;
    margin: 5px;   
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid 6</h2>
<div class="container" id="six">
    <div class="item item-1">item 1</div>
    <div class="item item-2">item 2</div>
    <div class="item item-3">item 3</div>
    <div class="item item-4">item 4</div>
    <div class="item item-5">item 5</div>
    <div class="item item-6">item 6</div>
</div>
```

as you can well see item 2 and 5 are out of place

Answer (score 0):

The content of the 2nd columns is overflowing because you set a fixed width to it with : `auto 50px auto`. It cannot exceed 50px width. You also gave it a 5px margin so the available space for the content is 40px.

To let the column size itself according to it's content, you can use : `1fr auto 1fr`.

Here is an example with your code :

```css
body{ 
    background-color: #E3E3E3;

}
#six.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
    [row1-start] "header header header" 40px [row1-end]
    [row2-start] "footer footer footer" 25px [row2-end]
    / 1fr auto 1fr;
    background-color: #FFF3E8;

}

#six .item{
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #F78100;
    background-color: #F89426;
    margin: 5px;   
}
```

```html
<h2>Grid 6</h2>
<div class="container" id="six">
    <div class="item item-1">item 1</div>
    <div class="item item-2">item 2</div>
    <div class="item item-3">item 3</div>
    <div class="item item-4">item 4</div>
    <div class="item item-5">item 5</div>
    <div class="item item-6">item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that makes sense but I kind of thought it will grow if its needed. You're saying for this to happened I need auto? what's its difference with fr?

Comment: @Pexicade I don't really understand what you mean. 1fr is like 1 fraction of the remaining space. if you want all 3 columns to have the same width, you need to use `1fr 1fr 1fr`